# Firefox wont show logs in browser

Tags: firefox, logs

I have some log files i posted to my web-server. when i navigate to them, I get prompted to download and open with a text editor.

on other distributions like fedora, and M$, the log opens in the browser, and i read it there. How can i get this functionality in Ubuntu?

Example:
http://nanocluster.umeche.maine.edu/e.log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following line in your **.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mime_module>

AddType text/plain .(your folder extension) 

</IfModule>
```

Restart apache and try .

Reply

Comment: I am still curios why fedora and other browsers worked.

Comment: am happy it waorks for you my friends cheers :)